# Why SOOT Cannot find the method calls from a dynamic loaded class?

Tags: java, static-analysis, soot

I am a beginner in learning soot and I was tormented by this strange problem: I create a instance of a class and I cannot find its methodcalls.

Here is the source code that I want to analyze:

```
package com.example.hello;

public class TestInputMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator calc = new Calculator();  // another class in same package, written by me. 

        int result = calc.add(10, 20); // I CANNOT FIND IT!!!

        System.out.println("The result of adding 10 and 20 is " + result);
    }
}
```

Here is part of soot codes that I use:

```
……
//SET UP CALL GRAPH
        String[] sootArgs = {
            "-pp",
            "-process-dir", jarFilePath, //I put them in a jar. The result is same without a jar
            "-allow-phantom-refs",
            "-no-bodies-for-excluded", 
            "-whole-program",
            "-verbose",
            "-p", "cg.cha", "enabled:true",
            "-dynamic-dir", jarFilePath,
        };
        Options.v().parse(sootArgs);

        String sootClassPath = jarFilePath;
        Options.v().set_soot_classpath(sootClassPath);

        Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();

        PackManager.v().getPack("wjtp").add(new Transform("wjtp.myTransform", new SceneTransformer() {
            @Override
            protected void internalTransform(String phaseName, Map<String, String> options) {
                CallGraph cg = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
……
//PRINT EVERY EDGE IN CALLGRAPH
                CallGraph callgraph = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
                Iterator<Edge> edgesdebug = callgraph.iterator();
                while (edgesdebug.hasNext()) {
                    Edge it = edgesdebug.next();
                    System.out.println("??????" + it.src() + " =>> " + it.tgt());
                }
```

The situation is, even if I print every edge in callgraph， including all kinds of lib functions, I still cannot find "add". I am crazy. I am dying.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Soot incorrectly. Where did you get your code from?
You are supposed to call soot.Main.main(..) after you have registered your transformer with Soot.